# Sprinter but now want to take part in marathon

Tags: training, running, marathon

I was a sprinter who used to run 100, 200 metres races, but now I'm training myself to improve my stamina and run long distance races.

I run on a treadmill 1 km everyday. Will a treadmill help me increase my stamina or do I have to choose an open field/road?

Also, I have completed **1 km** in **4:05** minutes, is it good enough if I'm preparing for a 10 km race? Half and full marathon is a distant dream as of now. Also, I want to run marathons as a personal achievement only.

I'm open for any valuable suggestions.

Comment: regarding the treadmill, see the fitness stack exchange post http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/40/is-there-any-benefit-of-real-running-outdoors-vs-running-on-a-treadmill-in-gym?rq=1

Comment: Hi, welcome to Sports.SE.  Unfortunately, this isn't a post that is appropriate here; we're all about *competitive* sports, so questions about running are focused on competitive running (olympic marathon questions and such).  Training is appropriate on [fitness.se], as you've already been directed to.

Comment: I respectively disagree.  The name of the forum is Sports and running in marathons is a competitive sport.   The question was on how to play this particular sport.

Comment: I'm voting to leave closed, as there are no concerns in this question specific to competitive running. Questions about running a specific distance in general are more about fitness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a nutshell, the trick to longer distance races is to train at those distances.  To run a 10 k race, work your way up to 8 or 9 k regularly before your race.  The same holds true for longer distance races.  To successfully run a half-marathon, train so that your training runs have increased to 15 to 18 k in month or so before the race.  When training for marathons, the longest training run is about 40 km.  That run takes place four to six weeks before the race.  Most training plans take into account the fact that most of us have jobs.  Distances are between 5 and 15 k during the week with the long run (working up to 40 k) on the weekend.

Speed doesn't play a whole lot into it except in learning how to regulate it.  Consistency in pacing is more important.

Being outside is great, but unless your race is hilly training on a treadmill is fine especially for the weekday runs.  Make use of the incline.

I really, really like Hal Higdon. Here's his beginner novice plan for a marathon.  You can see how the distances increase.  The plans for more advanced runners presume you are already running substantially longer distances.
http://www.halhigdon.com/training/51137/Marathon-Novice-1-Training-Program

And good luck.

Comment: After reading the article I realised that I can gradually increase my pace. I lose my pace after 1 km and I'm all tongue out! The article is awesome, so is your wonderful advice!